# How to get NSdocument directory saved video

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6

Currently, I am developing an app in which I have saved recorded video to document directory and my

code is here:

```
     NSURL * movieURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] ;

     NSData * movieData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:movieURL];

     NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

     NSString *documentsDirectory = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];

     NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[self video]text]];

     fullPath = [fullPath stringByAppendingFormat:@".MOV"];

      [movieData writeToFile:fullPath atomically:YES];
```

Now how can I check that videos are save in document directory or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get all saved video using this code:-

```
-(IBAction)getallVideo
{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *library = [path objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *fileArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:library error:nil];

    videolist  = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        for(int i = 0;i<fileArray.count;i++){
    NSLog(@"table%d",fileArray.count);
    id myArrayElement = [fileArray  objectAtIndex:i];
    if([myArrayElement rangeOfString:@".mp4" ].location !=NSNotFound)
    {
        [videolist addObject:myArrayElement];

    }
    else if([myArrayElement rangeOfString:@".mov"].location !=NSNotFound)
    {

    [videolist addObject:myArrayElement];
    }
 NSLog(@"Mu %@",videolist);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BOOL _isSaved = [movieData writeToFile:fullPath atomically:YES];

if(_isSaved == YES)}

   NSLog(@"Saved Succesfully")
}
else{

     NSLog(@"Error occured");
}
```

or

```
 NSError* error;
[movieData writeToFile:storePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];

if(error == nil){

  NSLog(@"Saved Succesfully")

}
 else{

         NSLog(@"write error %@", error);
 }
```

Comment: or   BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fullPath];
    if (success){ NSLog(@"file already exists");}